# Change php.ini to max execution 120

Tags: php

I found the php.ini file, but I don't see where to change max execution to 120.  Thank you for your support.

Comment: Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini      I ran this to find the php.ini.  How do I access it?

Answer (score 1):

Open the `php.ini` file in your favorite text editor.

Search for `max_execution_time`. It'll probably be set to something like 30 or 60.

Change it to 120 and save the file.

You'll likely need to restart your web server before the change takes affect.